# Comparing two dates on PHP when date format on Database is "Apr 5 2013"

Tags: php, database, date

Hi everyone im stuck with this: I want to erase records on a database that are in the past. I just want to get into account Month and Day. For example, if the database record is (this is how is formatted on the DB) "Apr 5 2013" i need to compare it with today's date "Apr 6 2013". In this case, this record gets deleted. I´ve seen examples using UNIX timestamp, but none using that format using the date('M j Y'). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The better way to store dates in databases is using DATE or DATETIME format. SQL allows you to get all informations you want from those types. But a request like this should work.

You could do it eventually with a regular expression, but it would be very heavy...

But you can do it in PHP, getting all results, then browsing them and comparing dates using something like `strtotime`, and then deleting every ID. Still very heavy but easier to implement than within a SQL request. But it still would be better if you could change the SQL architecture.

Answer (score 0):

The approach I would try would be to convert the english text string into a unix timestamp using [strtotime()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) then compare the new timestamp to the current date. Here is some php pseudo-code that describes the approach.

```
$threshold_to_deletion = numbers of days old a record is allowed to be;
$is_it_yesterday = 0;
$current_date = new DateTime();
$current_date->getTimestamp();

if ( !($is_it_yesterday = strtotime($str_from_db)) === false ) {
    $date_interval = date_diff($is_it_yesterday, $current_date);
    if( $date_interval >= $threshold_to_deletion ) {
        Do stuff here to delete
    }
} else {
    echo "DB string is not a valid date: $str_from_db";
}
```

Please note it is not finished or tested, it's just there to loosely describe how it would be done. I hope this helps.

Tim Dumas

[www.mpact-media.com](http://www.mpact-media.com)